# cannot convert from 'dataset' to 'system.data.dataset'

Tags: dataset

I'm struggling with what seems to be an innocent block of code. When I type in "FILL", the intellisence recognizes the method and gives me a hint with 5 overloads and one of them (3rd) actually says it accepts dataset and a string as parameters. This is what I am passing and yet the compiler seems confused by something as it puts the red squiggly line right underneath the last statement in the code below (adapter.Fill(ds, "tbl");). Sometimes, I erase it and re-type it again and then it says **"Error    1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(int, int, params System.Data.DataTable[])' has some invalid arguments...."** As if it's totally confused by which overloaded method of FILL I'm trying to use.

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string strSQL = "SELECT * from myTableName";        

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionStrng"))
    {

        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, cn))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "tbl");

        }
    }

}
```

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

TIA,
-Tony.

Comment: That code compiles fine. Are you just getting intellisense errors, or compilation errors? If compilation errors, you probably have a `using` up top that causes DataSet to be something other than `System.Data.DataSet`. Alternatively you could change your `DataSet ds = new DataSet()` to `System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet()`

Comment: Hi,I only have 2 using's:

using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: I changed DataSet to System.Data.DataSet and it worked (weird). I added
using System.Data op top and only left DataSet and it gave me compile errors again. Why would it do that?

Comment: System  
    System.Data.Sqlclient'

Comment: add a using for `System.Data`.

Comment: I did that and it still didn't compile. It only compiled when I explicitly added System.Data in front of DataSet